# How and When to dispose an object in C#?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have to read large amount of Blob data (more then 300Gb) from a db and insert into another db.I am reading data by using following code

```
if (dr.HasRows)
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
       media m = new media
       {
           docid = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"]),
           Content = Convert.ToByte(dr["BlobData"]),
           madiaName = Convert.ToString(dr["Name"])
       }
    }

    InsertInNewDb(m);
}
```

I am reading row by row and inserting data in asnother db.The problem is that memory full exception generates after sending some data as i am not disposing objects.
How to dispose object after a single iteration ?

Comment: "I have to read large amount of Blob data (more then 300Gb) " - erm, wtf! You would have to buffer and read in chunks...Largest single .NET object is 2GB.

Comment: Disposal isn't the problem, unless you have 300GB of memory, you can't read that much into memory.

Comment: Disposing objects has nothing to do with memory. It has to do with releasing unmanaged resources like file handles.

Comment: BTW, I think you're probably asking about disposing an object, unless you think that a "class object" is something different.

Comment: I am asking about disposing a class object

Comment: `Convert.ToByte` returns a single byte.. so you're only transferring a single byte. Given that fact.. I'd say its the code surrounding this that is the issue. You should be using `SqlReader.GetBytes` to read the bytes in chunks from the stream. See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getbytes.aspx

Comment: The code doesn't make sense? You are inserting the media after the whole dr.read() which means only one media object?

Comment: Running `GC.Collect()` may help a little, but there's probably a bigger root to the problem.

Comment: Media (BTW please use C# recommended naming for public sample code) seems to be very small (int+byte+sting), so it is not a problem. Most likely your app is 32bit and your are hitting LOH fragmentation wile reading from Reader that you can't really dispose (unless your sample is completely unrelated to your real code). Note that sample shows only last item copied to the new DB...

Comment: Convert.ToByte is not an issue i have write it just as an example the main problem is how to free object memory in while (dr.Read())

Comment: i have tried by setting object to null

Comment: Perhaps giving us actual code would help. Giving us a stripped down example that doesn't actually represent the issue means we can only guess..

Comment: Why don't you do this on the SQL server side? Insert all the data from one db to another in a single shot or in batches..

Comment: What is a "class object"? Is it different from an "object"?

Comment: Also, `m = null;` is not useful in .NET. This is not VB6.

Comment: People, although the OP has a lot to learn, I don't see why to downvote, or why to close as "not a real question". It's a real, on-topic question from someone who has quite a bit to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tie a number of answers and comments together, try something like this:

```
// The SqlConnection, SqlCommand and SqlDataReader need to be in using blocks
// so that they are disposed in a timely manner. This does not clean  up
// memory, it cleans up unmanaged resources like handles
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM OldTable", conn))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                   media m = new media
                   {
                       // Don't convert - cast instead. These are already the correct
                       // type.
                       docid = (int) dr["Id"],
                       // There are more efficient ways to do this, but
                       // Convert.ToByte was copying only a single byte
                       Content = dr["BlobData"],
                       madiaName = (string)dr["Name"]
                   }

                    // You probably want to insert _all_ of the rows.
                    // Your code was only inserting the last
                    InsertInNewDb(m);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try paginate the DataReader, this should to work. Try too to close both connections, source and target of data after some rows. Remember use objects with **using** instruction for better manage of memory.

Comment: How to use objects with in use statements ? It shows that a class should be idisposable

Comment: Sorry, I mean with connection objects, command and datareader etc.

Comment: His object should be implementing IDosposable to use with `using` block..